# Meaning of "uniformly sampling"?

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution, sampling

Reading an article I came across the following expression:

'' $\overline{X}$ is constructed by sampling uniformly along the straight line between the pair of $X$ and $\hat{X}$."

I know what a uniform distribution is but I have never come across the expression "sampling uniformly". I was first wondering if they just mean randomly sampling any point which lies on that straight line between the two points $X$ and $\hat{X}$ but I assume, that randomly sampling is unrelated to uniformly sampling.

Comment: I think that “randomly sampling any point which lies on that straight line” is technically ill-defined unless you specify how you are sampling, but that when people say “randomly” without any further specification, they usually mean uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they they are placing a uniform distribution on the line segment between $X$ and $\hat{X}$, and sampling from this distribution, just as you sample from the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, for example.